# What does the notation self(x) do?

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, self

I'm learning about Distributional RL from 'Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands On' [code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/blob/master/Chapter07/07_dqn_distrib.py). And there is a method in model class:

```
    def both(self, x):
        cat_out = self(x)
        probs = self.apply_softmax(cat_out)
        weights = probs * self.supports
        res = weights.sum(dim=2)
        return cat_out, res
```

What does that self(x) do/mean?

Comment: That depends on what the `__call__()` method for your class is defined to do. Without knowing that, there *is* no defined meaning.

Comment: Calling the [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method of the object. It is equivalent to `self.__call__(x)`.

Comment: Please ensure, before asking a question, that what you provide is a [mre] -- code complete enough someone else can see the same behavior without needing to add anything that isn't in the question (but with nothing included that *isn't* strictly needed for that purpose).

Comment: What does anything(x) do? Now set self = anything: everything is an object in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will call the `__call__` method on the instance. See this demo:

```
class A:
    def __call__(self, x):
        print("called instance")
        return x + 3

    def both(self, x):
        val = self(x)
        print("value:", val)


a = A()
a.both(5)
print()
a(123)
a.__call__(123)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> called instance
> value: 8
>
> called instance
> called instance
> ```

Doing `val = self(x)` is *identical* to doing `val = self.__call__(x)`.